# Encontrar sequencia em um valor inteiro

Tags: javascript, node.js, algoritmo

Eu cheguei  ao seguinte algoritmo pra retornar `true` caso exista um padrão sequencial numérico incremental +1

```
 function sequenceSearch(vector) {
          let pos = 0;
          let found = 0;
          for (pos = 0; pos <= vector.length - 1; pos++) {
            if (vector[pos] + 1 === vector[pos + 1]) {
              found++;
            }
          }
          return found == 3 ? true : false;
        }
```

Entretanto, na chamada da função preciso passar um valor int e não um vetor, como o necessário no algoritmo representado. Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de transformar um valor inteiro, exemplo: `int value = 1234`, em um array para ser avaliado pelo algoritmo. ( Ou alguma outra alternativa mais prática para encontrar o padrão)

Comment: Pegue consecutivamente o resto da divisão do número por 10, coloque-o em seu array e divida o número por 10 até que seja <= 0. Seu array estará com os algarismos em ordem invertida mas você pode facilmente tratar isso em seu teste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o parâmetro vector não for array ele será convertido para array

```
function sequenceSearch(vector) {
    vector = Array.isArray(vector) ? vector : vector.toString().split('').map(Number);
    let pos = 0;
    let found = 0;
    for (pos = 0; pos <= vector.length - 1; pos++) {
        if (vector[pos] + 1 === vector[pos + 1]) {
            found++;
        }
    }
    return found == 3 ? true : false;
}

var value = 1234;

console.log(sequenceSearch(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode transformar o número em uma string e fazer o split dele, criando um array... Criei uma função que recebe um array e converte ele pra Int (importante realmente todos serem números ou criar um tratamento pra isso), essa função retorna um array de inteiros que pode ser jogado dentro da sua função.

Alterei um pouco da sua função também, agora ela vai servir pra qualquer diferença numérica. Problema no caso do número '246810', pois ele separa o '10'. Caso não queira isso apenas use a que já tem mesmo.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
function sequenceSearch(vector) {
    let pos = 0;
    let found = 0;
    let dif = vector[1] - vector[0]; // variavel de diferença
    for (pos = 0; pos <= vector.length - 1; pos++) {
      if (vector[pos] + dif === vector[pos + 1]) {
        found++;
      }
    }
    return found == vector.length -1 ? true : false; // verificando pelo tamanho do array menos 1, agora pode receber array de qualquer tamanho
  }

//a nova funcao que eu criei para converter o array
function transformaArray (array) {
    array.forEach((e, i, a) => {
        a[i] = parseInt(e, 10);
    });
    return array;
}

let value = 1234;

//um exemplo de como chamar as funcoes
console.log(sequenceSearch(transformaArray(value.toString().split('')))); //retornando true
```

Teste foi feito com os valores '1234', '123456', '369' e '2468'. Todos retornaram 'true'

Teste feito com os valores '1258', '4789' e '2458'. Todos retornaram 'false'.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas ai, eu teria um array de strings, que por ventura  não conseguiria estar realizando a soma em sequencia, pois os valores se concatenariam.

Comment: Boa observação. Alterei a resposta. Vê se vai te atender.